Custom field at woocommerce checkout page not working
I am trying to add some customize fields at woocommerce check out page, Trying to follow woocommerce documentations sample code as well as other codes avaible through internet ,but none of them worked. To avoid theme or plugin conflict I also tried the code in wordpress fresh installtion at local host. But no response. I have to populate the customized fields based on number of products selected on basket page , so I prefer solution through code rarther any plugin for customize field.
The code I am trying to add a customize filed on checkout page of woocommerce is following:
`<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . esc_html__( 'My Field' ) . '</h2>';

woocommerce_form_field(
    'my_field_name',
    array(
        'type'        => 'text',
        'class'       => array( 'my-field-class form-row-wide' ),
        'label'       => __( 'Fill in this field' ),
        'placeholder' => __( 'Enter something' ),
    ),
    $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' )
);

echo '</div>';

} ?>`
Woocommerce documentation I am trying :
https://developer.woocommerce.com/docs/customizing-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/
My site link:
https://nin-london.uk/product/nin-card/
System Status Report
System Status Report
### WordPress Environment ###

WordPress address (URL): [Redacted]
Site address (URL): [Redacted]
WC Version: 9.1.4
Legacy REST API Package Version: The Legacy REST API plugin is not installed on this site.
Action Scheduler Version: ✔ 3.8.1
Log Directory Writable: ✔
WP Version: 6.6.2
WP Multisite: –
WP Memory Limit: 256 MB
WP Debug Mode: –
WP Cron: ✔
Language: en_GB
External object cache: –

### Server Environment ###

Server Info: Apache
PHP Version: 8.1.29
PHP Post Max Size: 8 MB
PHP Time Limit: 30
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
cURL Version: 8.10.0
OpenSSL/1.1.1w

SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 5.7.41
Max Upload Size: 8 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Multibyte String: ✔
Remote Post: ✔
Remote Get: ✔

### Database ###

[REDACTED]

### Post Type Counts ###

attachment: 76
custom_css: 1
customize_changeset: 3
elementor_library: 2
nav_menu_item: 20
page: 35
popup: 2
popup_theme: 8
post: 2
product: 2
revision: 103
shop_order_placehold: 1
template: 1
wp_font_face: 33
wp_font_family: 12
wp_global_styles: 1
wpforms: 8
wpforms-views: 1

### Security ###

Secure connection (HTTPS): ✔
Hide errors from visitors: ✔

### Active Plugins (30) ###

Advanced Custom Fields: by WP Engine – 6.3.6
BeCustom: by Muffin Group – 1.0.4
Custom status for Booknetic: by FS Code – 1.1.4
Custom forms for Booknetic: by FS Code – 2.2.4
Reports for Booknetic: by FS Code – 1.1.4
User Role Manager add-on for Booknetic: by FS Code – 1.1.9
Email action for Booknetic workflows: by FS Code – 1.2.6
Twilio SMS action for Booknetic workflows: by FS Code – 1.1.4
Webhook action for Booknetic workflows: by FS Code – 1.1.5
Booknetic: by FS-Code – 4.0.9
Code Snippets: by Code Snippets Pro – 3.6.5.1
Database for WPforms: by wpdebuglog – 1.0.6
Elementor: by Elementor.com – 3.24.4
Essential Addons for Elementor: by WPDeveloper – 6.0.5
Imagify: by Imagify – Optimize Images & Convert WebP & Avif – 2.2.2
LoginWP (Formerly Peter's Login Redirect): by LoginWP Team – 3.0.8.6
Redirection: by John Godley – 5.5.0
Slider Revolution: by ThemePunch – 6.5.11
W3 Total Cache: by BoldGrid – 2.7.5
WP Menu Cart: by WP Overnight – 2.14.6
WooPayments: by WooCommerce – 8.0.2 (update to version 8.2.2 is available)
WooCommerce: by Automattic – 9.1.4 (update to version 9.3.3 is available)
WP Data Access: by Passionate Programmers B.V. – 5.5.12
WP File Manager: by mndpsingh287 – 8.0
WP Mail SMTP: by WP Mail SMTP – 4.1.0
WP-Optimize - Clean, Compress, Cache: by David Anderson
Ruhani Rabin
Team Updraft – 3.5.0

WPForms Calculations: by WPForms – 1.2.0
WPForms Form Pages: by WPForms – 1.10.0
WPForms Signatures: by WPForms – 1.11.0
WPForms: by WPForms – 1.9.0.4

### Inactive Plugins (16) ###

Akismet Anti-spam: Spam Protection: by Automattic - Anti-spam Team – 5.3.3
Amelia: by TMS – 6.5
BeTheme Header Builder: by Muffin group – 1.0.7.3
Big File Uploads: by Infinite Uploads – 2.1.2
Font Awesome: by Font Awesome – 4.5.0
Force Regenerate Thumbnails: by Exactly WWW – 2.1.4
Formidable Forms: by Strategy11 Form Builder Team – 6.14
Go Live Update Urls: by OnPoint Plugins – 6.8.0
Hello Dolly: by Matt Mullenweg – 1.7.2
Jetpack: by Automattic – 13.7
LayerSlider: by Kreatura Media – 7.0.5
Popup Maker: by Popup Maker – 1.19.0
Site Kit by Google: by Google – 1.132.0
Widget Importer & Exporter: by ChurchThemes.com – 1.6.1
WPBakery Page Builder: by Michael M - WPBakery.com – 6.7.0
WP SMS: by VeronaLabs – 6.9.4.1

### Dropin Plugins () ###

advanced-cache.php: advanced-cache.php
maintenance.php: maintenance.php

### Must Use Plugins (1) ###

Elementor Safe Mode: by Elementor.com – 1.0.0

### Settings ###

API Enabled: –
Force SSL: –
Currency: GBP (£)
Currency Position: left
Thousand Separator: ,
Decimal Separator: .
Number of Decimals: 2
Taxonomies: Product Types: external (external)
grouped (grouped)
simple (simple)
variable (variable)

Taxonomies: Product Visibility: exclude-from-catalog (exclude-from-catalog)
exclude-from-search (exclude-from-search)
featured (featured)
outofstock (outofstock)
rated-1 (rated-1)
rated-2 (rated-2)
rated-3 (rated-3)
rated-4 (rated-4)
rated-5 (rated-5)

Connected to WooCommerce.com: –
Enforce Approved Product Download Directories: ✔
HPOS feature enabled: ✔
Order datastore: Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\DataStores\Orders\OrdersTableDataStore
HPOS data sync enabled: –

### Logging ###

Enabled: ✔
Handler: Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\Admin\Logging\LogHandlerFileV2
Retention period: 30 days
Level threshold: –
Log directory size: 15 KB

### WC Pages ###

Shop base: #940 - /shop/
Basket: #941 - /basket/ -  Contains the woocommerce/cart block
Checkout: #942 - /checkout/ -  Contains the woocommerce/checkout block
My account: #943 - /my-account/
Terms and conditions: ❌ Page not set

### Theme ###

Name: Betheme Child
Version: 2.0
Author URL: https://muffingroup.com
Child Theme: ✔
Parent Theme Name: Betheme
Parent Theme Version: 27.5.7.1
Parent Theme Author URL: https://muffingroup.com/
WooCommerce Support: ✔

### Templates ###

Archive Template: Your theme has a woocommerce.php file. You will not be able to override the woocommerce/archive-product.php custom template since woocommerce.php has priority over archive-product.php. This is intended to prevent display issues.
Overrides: betheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php
betheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-totals.php
betheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php
betheme/woocommerce/cart/cross-sells.php
betheme/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php
betheme/woocommerce/cart/proceed-to-checkout-button.php
betheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php
betheme/woocommerce/content-product.php
betheme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php
betheme/woocommerce/global/form-login.php
betheme/woocommerce/loop/loop-end.php
betheme/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php
betheme/woocommerce/loop/no-products-found.php
betheme/woocommerce/loop/pagination.php
betheme/woocommerce/myaccount/downloads.php
betheme/woocommerce/notices/error.php
betheme/woocommerce/notices/success.php
betheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/external.php
betheme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php
betheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php
betheme/woocommerce/single-product/related.php
betheme/woocommerce/single-product/sale-flash.php
betheme/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php
betheme/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/tabs.php
betheme/woocommerce/single-product/title.php
betheme/woocommerce/single-product/up-sells.php
betheme/woocommerce/single-product-reviews.php


### WooPayments ###

Version: 8.0.2
Connected to WPCOM: Yes
WPCOM Blog ID: 233891200
Account ID: ❌ Not connected
Logging: Disabled

### Admin ###

Enabled Features: activity-panels
analytics
product-block-editor
coupons
core-profiler
customize-store
customer-effort-score-tracks
import-products-task
experimental-fashion-sample-products
shipping-smart-defaults
shipping-setting-tour
homescreen
marketing
mobile-app-banner
navigation
onboarding
onboarding-tasks
product-custom-fields
remote-inbox-notifications
remote-free-extensions
payment-gateway-suggestions
shipping-label-banner
subscriptions
store-alerts
transient-notices
woo-mobile-welcome
wc-pay-promotion
wc-pay-welcome-page
launch-your-store

Disabled Features: experimental-blocks
minified-js
pattern-toolkit-full-composability
product-pre-publish-modal
printful
settings
async-product-editor-category-field
product-editor-template-system

Daily Cron: ✔ Next scheduled: 2024-09-30 14:27:31 +01:00
Options: ✔
Notes: 74
Onboarding: completed

### Action Scheduler ###

Complete: 537
Oldest: 2024-08-29 21:24:14 +0100
Newest: 2024-09-29 16:10:04 +0100

Failed: 2,437
Oldest: 2023-10-10 00:22:58 +0100
Newest: 2024-09-29 16:14:43 +0100

Pending: 17
Oldest: 2024-09-29 16:19:43 +0100
Newest: 2024-10-06 12:46:26 +0100


### Status report information ###

Generated at: 2024-09-29 16:15:15 +01:00
</details>

